# Generate row based on zip code start and end range value in snowflake using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Sample Data:

Code using SQL only no stored proc.

| Card No | StartZip | EndZip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 786**** | 97000 | 97003 |
| 787**** | 98000 | 98003 |

Expected output

| Card No | ZipCode |
| --- | --- |
| 786*** | 97000 |
| 786*** | 97001 |
| 786*** | 97002 |
| 786*** | 97003 |
| 787*** | 98000 |
| 787*** | 98001 |
| 787*** | 98002 |
| 787*** | 98003 |

Comment: JOIN a zipcode table.

Comment: Please check the question properly. I need to generate row for each zip code based on range values.

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you've managed to write so far and explain the specific issue you are facing. People on this site will help you but is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake you can also write a recursive CTE to avoid joins:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ZipCodeRange AS (
  SELECT CardNo, StartZip AS ZipCode, EndZip
  FROM <NAME OF YOUR TABLE>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT z.CardNo, z.ZipCode + 1 AS ZipCode, z.EndZip
  FROM ZipCodeRange z
  WHERE z.ZipCode < z.EndZip
)
SELECT CardNo, ZipCode
FROM ZipCodeRange
ORDER BY CardNo, ZipCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
WITH nums AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY seq4())-1 AS num
    FROM TABLE(generator(rowcount => 100000))
), input AS (
    SELECT Card_No, StartZip, EndZip
      FROM (VALUES ('786****',  97000,  97003),
                   ('787****',  98000,  98003)) t(Card_No, StartZip, EndZip)
)
SELECT i.Card_No, i.StartZip, i.EndZip, i.StartZip + n.num AS ZipCode
  FROM input AS i
  LEFT JOIN nums AS n ON i.StartZip + n.num <= i.EndZip
 ORDER BY i.Card_No, ZipCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lateral join on flattened array of all zip codes generated using `array_generate_range`

```
 select card_no, b.value as zip_code
 from t, lateral flatten(array_generate_range(start_zip, end_zip + 1)) b
```